# Python readline() is not reading a line with single space

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline

I am reading a text file using readline(). My file contains below content with a space at second line:

```
!

"
#
$
%
&
```

When I print read values using-

```
print("'%s'\n" % iso5_char)
```

It prints-

```
'!'

''

'"'

'#'

'$'

'%'

'&'
```

It seems that readline() not reading the 'space' at second line.

I am using python for the first time. I have python-3.5 installed. What is wrong I am doing here? Why is space not read?

UPDATE:
Screenshot of the file i amreading:

[image]

Comment: How do you know there's a space there? Are you _certain_ there's a space? As in, a literal space character, not just a blank line when you look at it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes. There is a space. I added it on purpose.

Comment: Well, in the example you pasted into your question, there is no space, but this may be due to SO auto format stuff... or maybe the editor you created the file with is doing the same? Check whether it automatically removed whitespace at the end of a line!

Comment: please show the code that is reading the file.

Comment: yes.. that could be reason here..

Comment: _A blank line is represented by a `\n`_ - so you don't have a space, you have an empty line.

Comment: @BryanOakley the code- iso5_char = I5F.readline()
 iso5_char = iso5_char.rstrip()
 print("'%s'\n" % iso5_char)

Comment: Try to configure your editor to show trailing whitespace

Comment: Note that `readline()` does not strip the line end character, so you are _definitely_ removing whitespace after reading the line, otherwise there should be a linebreak before the closing `'`. UPDATE: Yes, here `iso5_char = iso5_char.rstrip()` you remove both the `\n` and the space.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `.rstrip()` does :)

Comment: Add the code to the question (via the "edit"-link). `rstrip` removes whitespace from the right, so that's the problem

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I thought rstrip removes the new line character and retains rest..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a comment to the original question,  you are explicitly stripping out the space with this expression:

```
iso5_char.rstrip()
```

From the documentation for `rstrip`:

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the end of the string this method is called on.

In this context, "whitespace" refers to spaces, tabs, newlines, carriage returns, formfeeds, and vertical tabs.

If your intent with `rstrip` is to only strip trailing newlines, you can pass a newline to the `rstrip` command:

```
iso5_char.rstrip('\n')
```

Or, you can simply chop off the last character since it's safe to assume it's a newline:

```
iso5_char[:-1]
```

Comment: How could I retrieve the whitespace in this case?

Comment: @MSharathHegde: what do you mean "retrieve the whitespace"? Do you mean "not strip out the whitespace"? If your intent is to only strip out the newline, give a newline as an argument to `rstrip`: `rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: Yes, I mean not to remove space. Thank you for the solution.. rstrip('\n') is working..